# Debugging Java programs with command line arguments from Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, command-line, ide, vscode-extensions

I'm using the "Extension Pack for Java" by Microsoft.
It works fine, I can add new class files, compile, run and debug them.
If I run extension command "Java: Create Java Project" I get a nice setup with subfolders for libraries, "binaries" and source, i.e. ./lib, ./bin, ./src.

However, now I need to call a program with command line arguments.

I can go to the terminal and run the program with command line arguments:

java .\src\HelloWorld.java Argument1 Argument2

or compile it in VSC and run it from terminal using:

java .\bin\ HelloWorld Argument1 Argument2

However, how can I add the arguments when starting the application from VSC? (running and/or debugging).

I've seen and tried quite a few guides on setting up various .json "settings" files for VSC but none of them seem to match the Java Extension pack setup.

What is the simplest possible solution? (simple as in fewest possible text lines in .json file).

Comment: Eclipse has a "launch" parameter dialog.  Surely VSCode has something similar in the "Run" and "Debug" menus?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add args parameter to a launch configuration:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_configuration-options